# Check if element is disable using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

So i have this `WebElement` (now in disable mode):

```
<select id="id1" name="name" disabled=""><option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
<option value="true">Yes</option></select>
```

Not disable:

```
<select id="id1" name="name" ><option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
<option value="true">Yes</option></select>
```

So my question is how to check if this element is disable or not ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use isDisplayed  method of WebElement.

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("id1"));
el.isDisplayed ()
```

Comment: But an element could be displayed AND disabled.

Answer (score 5):

u can use isEnabled() to verify whether it is enabled or disable.it returns boolean .if it returns true the element is enabled if it returns false the element is disabled.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @kumar you could add a link to the official docs (e.g. for Python it's: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check how many lists of elements are disabled or enabled, you can use the below syntax.

List btn = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

```
    int countEnable = 0;
    int countDisable = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < btn.size(); i++) {
        if (btn.get(i).isEnabled()) {
            countEnable++;
        } else
            countDisable++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total Enabled button available in web page is : " + countEnable);
    System.out.println("Total Disbaled button available in web page is " + countDisable);
```